# como acceder a la llave de un objeto a partir de un string?

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js, poo, vuejs

Tengo este problema. Utilizo javascript Vue y vuex

objeto:

```
{
  idioma: {
    es_mx: {
      titulo: "hola mundo"
    }
  }
}
```

Se que para imprimirlo o modificarlo basta con lo siguiente:

```
console.log(idioma.es_mx.titulo);
```

Pero por cuestiones de lógica y compactar el código. 
Quiero hacer un actualizador globalizado.

Mandaría a llamar a una función de la siguiente forma.

```
update_info('idioma.es_mx.titulo', 'Este es un nuevo texto');

function update_info(key, value){
  let point = data.point.split(".");
  switch (point .length) {
        case 1:
          state[point[0]] = value
          break;
        case 2:
          state[point[0]][point[1]] = value
          break;
        case 3:
          state[point[0]][point[1]][point[2]] = value
          break;

        case 4:
          state[point[0]][point[1]][point[2]][point[3]] = value
          break;
        case 5:
          state[point[0]][point[1]][point[2]][point[3]][point[4]] = value
          break;

      }

}
```

Esto resuelve el problema de forma practica y poco elegante.

Quisiera poder recorrer los puntos para generalizar el objetivo de la función.

Esto lo estoy ocupando en javascript.

Este es un ejemplo de lo que hace.

```js
var el = new Vue(
{
el: "#app",
data: {
value:null,
  idiomas: {
    es: {
      titulo: "hola mundo"
    },
    en:{
      titulo: "hola mundo"
    }
  }
},
methods: {

update_values(key, value){
let dt = this.idiomas;

let point = key.split(".");
  switch (point .length) {
        case 1:
         dt[point[0]] = value
          break;
        case 2:
          dt[point[0]][point[1]] = value
          break;
        case 3:
          dt[point[0]][point[1]][point[2]] = value
          break;
        case 4:
          dt[point[0]][point[1]][point[2]][point[3]] = value
          break;
        case 5:
          dt[point[0]][point[1]][point[2]][point[3]][point[4]] = value
          break;
      }
}
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3>Este es el mensaje que se modifica con un solo input</h3>
   <p>
    {{ idiomas.es.titulo }} 
   </p>
   <p>
    {{ idiomas.en.titulo }} 
   </p>
   
   <input v-model="value" type="text" @change="update_values('es.titulo', value)">
    
    <input  type="text" @change="update_values('en.titulo', value)">
</div>
```

Esto lo ocupo en una tienda de vuex.

Answer (score 0):

Reescribiendo la función update_values así pienso que te servirá:

```
update_values(key, value) {
  const keys = key.split('.');
  let i, dt = this.idiomas;
  for (i = 0; i < keys.length-1; i++) {
    dt = dt[keys[i]];
  }
  dt[keys[i]] = value;
}
```